# LocaleContextHolder does not return exact locale in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: locale, spring-cloud-gateway

Is there anyway to get current locale in Spring Cloud Gateway? I use `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` to get user's locale but it's always return default locale `en`.
Thank for your help!

```
@Component
public class ClientVersionGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<ClientVersionGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {
    private final MessageSource messageSource;

    public ClientVersionGatewayFilterFactory(MessageSource messageSource) {
        super(Config.class);
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return new GatewayFilter() {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

                Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
                String message = messageSource.getMessage("test", null, locale);

                exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().set("X-Custom-Locale", locale.getLanguage());
                exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().set("X-Custom-Test", message);

                return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
            }
        };
    }

    public static class Config {
    }
}
```

Comment: I seems `LocaleContextHolder` does not work with Spring WebFlux. I tested both MVC and WebFlux. `LocaleContextHolder` works only with MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to workaround.

```
Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale(exchange.getLocaleContext());
String message = messageSource.getMessage("test", null, locale);
```

Is there anyone have better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

becouse webflux not support ThreadLocal , you can get the header from exchange. you can defined a globalfilter, just like this

```
@Component
public class LocaleFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        List<Locale> acceptLocales = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getAcceptLanguageAsLocales();
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(acceptLocales)) {
            LocaleContextHolder.setDefaultLocale(acceptLocales.get(0));
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```